# Why was the CSS function clamp written into an Sass unquote function?

Tags: css, sass

In a project I took over, the style was written with **SCSS**. At one point I wonder why the CSS `clamp()` function was written with an unquote. If I remove unquote there is no difference.

```css
div {
  font-size:unquote("clamp(30px, 10px + 2%, 30px)");
}
```

**And without unquote**

```css
div {
  font-size:clamp(30px, 10px + 2%, 30px);
}
```

#### Question:

Why did you put the clamp function into an unquote function again? If it works without!

Comment: What makes you think that the one who wrote that code reads your post? Why not ask your colleague directly?

Comment: @NicoHaase ;. But the probability is very low. I agree with you there. I don't know the colleague who wrote that. Since I have never worked with Sass functions before, I thought it was generally valid. Maybe it's even you? ;-)

Comment: @MaikLowrey hahaha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what the documentation says:

> You can convert a quoted string to an unquoted string using the string.unquote() function, and you can convert an unquoted string to a quoted string using the string.quote() function.

So this means that the unquote function is basically useless, because the only thing it does is unquoting `"clamp(30px, 10px + 2%, 30px)"` which will result in `clamp(30px, 10px + 2%, 30px)` which is the exact same.

A reason someone can do this, is for bug reasons, if there is a bug in sass itself (the clamp function only works with unquote), so maybe that is the reason why the programmer has added this.

The probability of this specific bug is offcourse very low, but it is just a theory...

Comment: Could you please accept my answer, so that other people will know this question is answered?

Comment:  sure. i will do it

Answer (score 0):

The unquote function was probably used because the text in the function came from a string from an other program or service, so to make sure it will work as CSS they added that during the transfer to CSS.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That would be a possibility but I have the source code and here it is not inserted from another program. It was hard coded.

Answer (score 0):

The unquote function is added to avoid the compile time errors experienced with clamp property when used in a scss format. The scss fails to identify css units within the clamp function, the error thrown during the compile time for a property `font-size: clamp(1rem, 2vw + 1rem, 2rem);`  is given below:

```
Module build failed:                                                                                                          
font-size: clamp(1rem, 2vw + 1rem, 2rem);                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Incompatible units: 'rem' and 'vw'
```

if the same property is used with an unquote function no compile time errors are observed: `unquote("clamp(1rem, 2vw + 1rem, 2rem)")`

For further information do check [this](https://webdevpuneet.com/error-incompatible-units-vw-and-rem-in-scss-to-css-compiler/#gsc.tab=0) blog.